# Convert dynamic table to dax formula in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, dynamic-tables

I have the following formula in excel with 3 sheets/tables (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3) `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;sheet3!$A$2:$C$10000;3;FALSE);0)`

This formula looks for the ID in sheet 1 in sheet 3 which is a dynamic table made from sheet 2(A2) [image]

In a dynamic table with filters (sheet3): [image]

**Grupo Inicial**, **Estado Final** and **Estado Inicial** come from sheet2[image]

The thing is that the formula mentioned above is basic but it comes from the dynamic table which converting that into a formula and adding the basic formula to work with it is what I dont know how to do.

I have done this:

```
`Horas sin Pending = CALCULATE(SUM('sheet1'[Total horas laborables]);
'sheet2'[Grupo Inicial]="Soporte Identity";
'sheet2'[Estado Final]="Assigned";
'sheet2'[Estado Final]="In Progress";
'sheet2'[Estado Final]="Pending";
'sheet2'[Estado Final]="Resolved";
'sheet2'[Estado Inicial]="Assigned"; 
'sheet2'[Estado Inicial]="In Progress"; 
'sheet2'[Estado Inicial]="Resolved")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a relationship between Sheet1 and Sheet2 on field `ID de incidencia`, then try

```
Horas sin Pending = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'sheet2'[Total horas laborables] );
    FILTER ( 
        'sheet2';
        'sheet2'[Grupo Inicial] = "Soporte Identity" && 
        'sheet2'[Estado Inicial] <> "Pending" && 
        'sheet2'[Estado Inicial] <> "Closed"
    )
)
```

Comment: Can I add to that switch this in some way `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;sheet3!$A$2:$C$10000;3;FALSE);0)`? The iferror reference

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Nothing will be returned, if there's no matching value(s)... I'm concerned by this and previous posts by you and your colleague, that you're simply trying to replicate an Excel workbook in Power BI, though - there's almost certainly a more efficient way of achieving the outcome you want, than by lots of pre-aggregation in calculated columns.

Comment: Your totally right,  we are trying to replicate an excel directly into powerbi. This is something extraofficial we volunteered for at our job and are we are using a lot of our time on trying to accomplish it..

Comment: You might get better support by posting your project, including inputs and expected outcomes, on SuperUser.com